# IOS app installation freeze

Tags: ios, air

I developed an app for iOS in Adobe Air CS6 and when I try to put it on my iPhone 4 via iTunes it won't install.

The application appears on Springboard but it is dark, the title is set to "Installing" but nothing changes, it's frozen like that. I can't think of anything I've missed (provisioning profile, device number set, certificate).

Comment: if you had provisioning profile then you can create an ipa file right? and if yes then you can upload your ipa to http://www.diawi.com/ this website and then it will give you a link that you need to open in your safari and you'll be able to install your application. just alternative solution of your problem.

Comment: it doesn't work... it's installing continuously. :-|

Comment: hmm might be something wrong with your app, test it on simulator and check whether it's working or not?

Comment: I've had a similar case where the app actually WAS installing, but it left behind a "ghost app" like you describe. Check all the screens on your phone and make sure it definitely wasn't installed. I've only seen this happen on iOS 7

Comment: If you're running iOS 7, try the AIR 3.9 beta. It has some bugs (you'll want to develop with 3.8 still since there are quite a few issues with using the AIR Simulator), but it has some fixes you'll need for iOS 7 (including the 120x120 icon required by Apple for all iPhone apps now. You won't be able to publish with an SDK older than 3.9 anymore)

Comment: I will try this today with SDK 3.9 . I will tell you what happens. thanks until than .

Comment: do yo know where to put icon 120x120? because in flash option where I usually put icons there is not 120x120 icon...